# Apache Olingo(Java OData) Swagger API framework integration

Tags: swagger, olingo

I have a webapp in Tomcat which exposes OData endpoints through Apache Olingo. I have searched the web with keywords such as swagger, olingo, integration but have not found any answer.

There are some information aboout .NET OData Swagger integration but I'm not intrested in that.

Please note that I'm interested about Olingo and Swagger integration, not Swaggersocket integration.

Do anyone know if Swagger supports Olingo integration?

Edit: Does Swagger UI work seamlessly with Olingo integration?